# $A$ is equipotent to $B$, $C$ equipotent to $D$, $C \subset A$ and $D \subset B$. Prove $A \diagdown C$ is quipotent $B \diagdown D$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**Problem** $A$ is equipotent to $B$, $C$ equipotent to $D$, $C \subset A$ and $D \subset B$. Prove $A \diagdown C$ is quipotent $B \diagdown D$.

Let $A$ is equipotent to $B$, $C$ equipotent to $D$ then exists $f: A \rightarrow B$ and $g: C \rightarrow D$ bijectives functions. Then $f_{|C}: C \rightarrow B$ is a injetcive function. But I don't know how relate $A \diagdown B$ with $f \mbox{ or } g$ functions. Could you help me?

Comment: This is not true.

Comment: A typo: "quipotent"

Comment: Really? Dou you have any sets?

Comment: It's true for finite sets only.

Comment: Hint:  There are many a counterexample with $A=B=C=\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: It is false: counter example. $A = B = \mathbb{N}$, $C= \text{even numbers}$, $D=\text{finite set}$. Think it as cardinals: $a + b = c$, $a' + b' = c'$, $a=a'$, $c=c'$ does not imply $b=b'$